# FastReport for FMX corrupts styles/texts on other forms

Tags: windows, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, fastreport

I'm using FastReport component in Delphi XE5 FireMonkey (basically the Embarcadero edition). 
When I'm using the report component on one of my form, it is effecting styles/texts (font size mainly) on other forms on Windows 7 machine. 
When i remove the component and FMX.frxClass from uses section, then everything works well.

Does anybody have any idea what could be the reason for that?

Comment: You should *always* add the **delphi** tag to your Delphi related questions. If you ever wonder about low attention to your question, that is the reason. (the same with all tags containing a special version)

Answer (score 0):

> For units in the interface uses list, the initialization sections of the units used by a client are executed in the order in which the units appear in the client's uses clause.

Check the order in which you have units in your uses section and try moving FR to beginning or end. FR could initialize some global variables in a way that FMX does not expects.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for response. I've tried using it at both beginning and at the end. but the behavior is still same.

Comment: I've seen one more QC similar to this http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=125253

Comment: My problem was solved by setting GlobalUseDirect2D = True in .dpr file after Application.Initialize. But I am still not able to understand why Fast Report sets this variable to false. since i can see all the reports well after resetting this.